# Migrating from TFS to VSTS

Tags: tfs, migration

We are planning for a migration from TFS to VSTS, while going through some article online I came across the below migration tool.

**
 - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/05/12/migrating-your-data-from-tfs-to-visual-studio-online-with-new-free-utility-from-opshub/#comments
**

I have the following questions

- In the article it was mentioned that we don't need to upgrade to the latest version of TFS since the migration utility will read from TFS 2010,2012,2013.
- We have few projects in TFS 2008 and few in TFS 2013, according to the above statement we don't need to upgrade TFS 2013. But, what we have to do with TFS 2008 ? will this migration tool take cares of 2008 version as well or do we need to upgrade 2008 to 2013 and then start migrating to VSTS ?

Also, if anyone already has any experience with this tool can you please share your points ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, TFS 2008 is not supported by OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility. You will have to upgrade it to 2010 or higher in order to make it compatible with the migration tool.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-work-item-migrator

this migrator can do all 4 types of migrations of user stories
but you will need to download zip file and point that folder to new repo in vsts